# What is the set of all minimal 3CNF formulas?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

**Definition:** A **minimal** 3CNF formula is an **un**satisfiable 3CNF formula with **minimum** clauses connected by conjunctions, where each clause is disjunction of 3 literals, that is if **any** of it's clauses is removed from the formula, then the 3CNF formula becomes **satisfiable**.

For some natural number **n**, where **n** is the number of atomic variables, what is the set of all **minimal** 3CNF formulas? Is it finite? If it is finite then what is it's cardinality, i.e. how many **different minimal** 3CNF formulas is possible?

In a **minimal** **k**-cnf formula, there should be 2<sup>**k**</sup> different 
**k** literals clauses exactly, so in a **minimal** 3CNF formula, there should be 2<sup>3</sup>=8 different 3 literals clauses exactly.

That's what I think anyway, but correct me if I am wrong.

**Note** that for k-cnf formula n≥k, so in 3CNF formula n≥3.

Comment: If a 3CNF formula $P(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is minimal, then $P(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ is also minimal. So it may be better to fix the set of variables, not the size of it. (Or, count formulae up to α-equivalence.)

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. Can you explain me please?

Comment: For example, if $n=1$, then $(x \vee x \vee x) \wedge (\neg x \vee \neg x \vee \neg x)$ is minimal for every variable $x$. So if we fix the number of variables occurring in the formula, the number of minimal formulae is always infinite because the number of variables is infinite.

Comment: n suppose to be finite number, not infinite, so for particular n, the number of minimal formula should be finite, but not infinite, no? I have edited my question. Please read the update.

Comment: I may misunderstand the definition of $n$. Do you mean that, for example, "the number of atomic variables" of $(x \vee \neg x \vee y)$ is 3, not 2? Also, is $(x \vee \neg x \vee y)$ different from $(z \vee \neg z \vee w)$ when counting minimal 3CNFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of minimal formula is finite.  Indeed, if a formula is minimal, then no clause can be repeated.  Now there are $(2n)^3=8n^3$ possible clauses, so there are at most $2^{8n^3}$ different formulas with no repeated clauses.  Thus there are at most $2^{8n^3}$ minimal formula, which is finite.

I don't know of any clean way to count the number of minimal formula; probably there is no simple formula for it.  You could try computing the number for $n=1,2,3$ by brute-force, then looking up the resulting sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), but I don't expect you to find any simple expression for this number.

What you are thinking is wrong.  A minimal, unsatisfiable formula can have more than 8 clauses.

Comment: "An unsatisfiable formula can have more than 8 clauses" this is correct, but then it is probably not minimal, because probably there exists a possibility to remove any of it's clauses and it will remain unsatisfiable.

Comment: @ErezZrihen, see edited answer.  An unsatisfiable formula can have more than 8 clauses even if it is minimal.  I suggest you try to find an example (it will be a good exercise for you that will boost your understanding).

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Okay thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's possible that number of minimal 3CNF's is $2^{n+C_n^2+C_n^3} + 1$. At least, if we put n instead of 3, it will be $2^{2^n}$ which is true.

Comment: 2^(2^n) is double/super exponential!!! :O How did you get to these terrible results?

Comment: @ErezZrihen, number of possible formulas of $n$ variables is exactly $2^{2^n}$, since number of assignments is $2^n$ and number of their 
 [assignments] combinations is hyperexponential

Comment: hyperexponential? What is this? What that means? I don't understand what are you talking about, but I do know that number of assignments is 2^n for sure.

Comment: @ErezZrihen, hyperexponential, is $2^{exp}$. First, since number of assignments is $2^n$, we can say that truthtable can be seen as number of exponential length. But how large number can you represent with exponentialy many bits? Exactly $2^{2^n}$.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thank you for your answer.