# What is the set of all maximal 3CNF formulas?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

**Definition:** A **maximal** 3CNF formula is satisfiable 3CNF formula, but if you conjuct it with another any **new different** 3 disjuctive literals clause, then the formula becomes **un**satisfiable.

Please do**n't** confuse with the definition of **minimal** 3CNF formula from my previous question [What is the set of all minimal 3CNF formulas](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78052/what-is-the-set-of-all-minimal-3cnf-formulas)

This is **not** the same thing!

But my question about **minimal** 3CNF formulas in the above link is same for **maximal** 3CNF formulas here, i.e.

For some natural number **n**, where **n** is the number of atomic variables, what is the set of all **maximal** 3CNF formulas? Is it finite? If it is then what is it's cardinality, i.e. how many **different maximal** 3CNF formulas is possible?

**Note** that for k-cnf formula n≥k, so in 3CNF formula n≥3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^n$ maximal 3CNFs; here I am assuming that each 3-clause contains *at most* three different literals (corresponding to different variables), and that the clauses are different and unordered (both within each clause, and across the formula). Indeed, I show below that if $\varphi$ is a maximal 3CNF then there is a truth assignment $\alpha$ such that $\varphi$ consists of all 3-clauses consistent with $\varphi$, and conversely, each such formula is maximal.

Indeed, let $\varphi$ be a maximal 3CNF. Suppose first that $\varphi$ has at least two different truth assignments $\alpha,\beta$. There is a variable $x_i$ whose truth value is different in $\alpha$ and $\beta$, say $x_i$ is true in $\alpha$ but false in $\beta$. In particular, the clause $x_i$ is not in $\varphi$ (since $\beta$ doesn't satisfy it), and if we add it then the formula remains satisfiable. We conclude that $\varphi$ has a unique satisfying assignment $\alpha$. If $\varphi$ doesn't contain all 3-clauses consistent with $\alpha$ then we can add the missing ones while keeping the formula satisfiable. Thus $\varphi$ must consist of all 3-clauses consistent with $\alpha$.

Conversely, suppose that $\varphi$ consists of all 3-clauses consistent with $\alpha$. Since $\varphi$ contains all clauses of width 1, $\alpha$ is the unique satisfying assignment. By definition, any other 3-clause is inconsistent with $\alpha$, and so $\varphi$ is maximal.

You might be interested in E3CNFs, in which each 3-clause contain *exactly* three literals, each corresponding to a different variables. These can probably be analyzed using the same approach - if you're interested, you're welcome to work it through.

Comment: WoW! Quick answer! thank you! Glad to see it.